# vba regular expression last occurrence

Tags: regex, string, vba

I would like to match the **"775"** (representing the last 3 digit number with an unkown total number of occurrences) within the string **"one 234 two 449 three 775 f4our"** , with **"f4our"** representing an unknown number of characters (letters, digits, spaces, but not 3 or more digits in a row).

I came up with the regular expression **"(\d{3}).*?$"** thinking the **"?"** would suffice to get the **775** instead of the **234**, but this doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way to accomplish this using **VBA regular expressions**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `(\d{3}).*?$` just matches and captures into Group 1 the first 3 consecutive digits and then matches any 0+ characters other than a newline up to the end of the string.

You need to get the 3 digit chunk at the end of the string that is not followed with a 3-digit chunk anywhere after it.

You may use a negative lookahead `(?!.*\d{3})` to impose a restriction on the match:

```
\d{3}(?!.*\d{3})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qX7bE0/2). Or - if the 3 digits are to be matched as whole word:

```
\b\d{3}\b(?!.*\b\d{3}\b)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/qX7bE0/3)